# JSpinner with DateFormatter deletion behavior

Tags: java, swing, date-format, jspinner

So I created a spinner using JSpinner.DateEditor, and I changed the formatter a little to validate user input.

```
JSpinner sp1 = new JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(sp1, "hh:mm:ss a");

JFormattedTextField ftf = de.getTextField();
DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter) ftf.getFormatter();

formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
sp1.setEditor(de);
```

It works fine except one thing. For example the time is
11:32:12 AM

if I put my cursor before the colon that is between 32 and 12. I got
11:02:12 AM

but I want to get 
11:30:12 AM

Any help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the title of this question and described behavior, what is happening is explained in this line:

```
DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter) ftf.getFormatter();

formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); // here is the key
```

As per [DefaultFormatter#setAllowsInvalid()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultFormatter.html#setAllowsInvalid%28boolean%29) docs:

> `public void setAllowsInvalid(boolean allowsInvalid)`
>
> Sets whether or not the value being edited is allowed to be invalid
>   for a length of time (that is, `stringToValue` throws a `ParseException`).
>   It is often convenient to allow the user to temporarily input an
>   invalid value.

As you set this property in `false` you are not allowing users type an invalid value (for instance by deleting some character, or in this particular case by inserting some non digit character) and thus the formatter is trying to get the closest valid value.

It is not an unexpected behavior but necessary to keep consistency with the contract offered by this method.

Comment: There's no workaround because it's not a bug or an issue. In fact it's quite an advantage that the formatter actually takes care of an invalid input. Maybe it doesn't do it in the better way but consider this cases: a) Novice users will probably use mouse, not keyboard, to change the spinner value. b) Advanced users will probably use keayboard arrows to update values, so rarely they would have to delete anything. In both cases this behavior is something that users can live with. @user2628641